# Phrase for something that causes your battery to drain fast?

Tags: phrase-requests

I am familiar with the phrase ***battery hog***.

Is this a common phrase?

Is there any better expression?

Comment: "Drain on the battery" is probably a good as anything.  And I've probably heard "battery sucker" once or twice.

Comment: A quick search on google reveals the most common (that i can find anyway) phrase for this is `battery drain`, and returns over a million relevant results when searched. I more often hear people say that something `eats battery` although this doesn't seem to be very common on the internet

Comment: I personally like the fairly obscure term *vampire app*.

Comment: @technophyle Personally, I would go with "battery killer."

Comment: Thanks guys for all the answers. Every suggestion is quite valuable to me.

Comment: @Bookeater I agree that's an obscure term. With the right context, however, it will make sense, I think.

Answer (score 1):

**Battery hog** is a good expression. It would be instantly understood in the tech field. By way of analogy, we call CPU-intesive apps *CPU hogs*, as in *Chrome could be a huge CPU hog*.

Here's an example from CNet:

> GPS is a **huge battery hog**, as it harnesses data from the phone's GPS chip, cell phone towers, and Wi-Fi hotspots to find your location

(http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-get-better-battery-life-on-android/)

Or you can simply say **battery drainer**:

> Surprisingly, the Wal-Mart (WMT) app is the **top battery drainer** among U.S. Android users in this category.

(http://money.cnn.com/2015/06/03/technology/battery-draining-apps/)

The adjective **battery-intensive** could work as well:

> What are the most **battery intensive apps?**

(http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/what-are-the-most-battery-intensive-apps.1097790/)

Edit: These may not be very common, but they still, I think, deserve a mention:

[**battery killer**](http://esr.ibiblio.org/?p=4886):

> No, GPSD is not the battery-killer on your Android!

[**juice-killer**](https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/comments/3hgo8y/question_can_somebody_help_me_figure_out_what_is/):

> Can somebody help me figure out what is draining my battery so much? - springtomize is definitely **a juice killer**...

**[juice-drainer](http://www.androidauthority.com/community/threads/inquiry-about-note-4-battery.8776/)**:

> The big Note 4 big screen will likely be **a real battery juice drainer**.

Answer (score 0):

The google search (with quotes) returns 60,000 results, so, yes, it's pretty popular. I mean, common. I mean, common and/or popular. Not exactly witty or beautiful, but pretty popular nonetheless. I mean, common. Yes. Right.

Comment: Any synonymous phrases that come to your mind?

Comment: I don't know ... Juice guzzler?

Comment: Sorry I'm not a native speaker, so it's hard for me to distinguish a joke. You're kidding right?

Comment: Only half-kidding, actually. A car is a gas (petrol, if you will) guzzler if it consumes too much gas (petrol). "Juice" is a slang word for electric power. Thus an application (such as Google Chrome) can theoretically be referred to as a juice guzzler. I'm not sure whether it's popular or not.